# Google Maps v1 NPE crash

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having a crash on my application due to a crash in Google Maps code. It's still the version 1 of Google play services (4.x)

I'm totally unable to reproduce this crash. (Nexus 5x, Galaxy S4) I can't find something similar on the internet (neither the same issue nor another one with the same method calls/etc. )

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{[xxx].app2/[xxx].app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.es.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.es.<init>(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.af.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.w.onTransact(SourceFile:66)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate$a$a.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$a.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$3.b(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$1.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$b.ip(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$b.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at [xxx].app.views.MapWithSearchView.onCreate(MapWithSearchView.java:124)
       at [xxx].app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:279)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Where `[xxx]` is my application package name.

Comment: It is a NPE.You are using the .iterate() on a  list which is null.

Comment: @kgandroid Yep, but as you can see the NPE is inside Google Maps (so, not my code). Has someone else encounter something similar before?

Comment: (MainActivity.java:279...what is written on that line??

Comment: @kgandroid `mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: @kgandroid and on 124 of `MapWithSearchView`: `mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`. With `mMapView` that is `MapView`